# Trying to understand difference between canActivate and Resolver

Tags: angular

I know canActivate calls before Resolver. I have a scenario that based on a token (dynamic from url) I need to route to three different pages. Which is a better approach.

Should I use canActivate and get the data from service based on the token and route. Or I should use Resolver service to get the data based on the token and route to the component?

Answer (score 22):

**CanActivate** is a router guard that is executed to check if the router should navigate to the route and the **Resolver** is a data provider, that fetch data for the component before the router starts navigation. So, because you are trying to fetch data, you should use a Resolver and not a Guard.

Answer (score 20):

The Resolver is really set up to be used for retrieving data. It automatically adds the data to a data[] that you can then access from the routed component to get that data:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movie = this.route.snapshot.data['movie'];
}
```

`canActivate` doesn't do that and is meant more for logic executed before activating a route ... such as checking whether the user is logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not have enough reputations to select the answer.

Comment: There is sometimes a delay before it will allow selection of an answer. But it should allow you to select an answer to your own question.

Comment: If I am using ngrx store, should I use resolver for fetching data? Even the data are fetched into store instead of returning to data[]? In such case should I return store.pipe(select(fetchedDataSelector))?